# How declare Xamarin.Forms.Dependency with F#?

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#, microblink, blinkid

I'm porting from C# this code:

```
using MicroBlink;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (BlinkIDImplementation))]
namespace BlinkIDApp.iOS
{
    public class BlinkIDImplementation : IBlinkID
    {
        CustomDelegate customDelegate;
        bool isFrontCamera;

        public BlinkIDImplementation ()
        {
            customDelegate = new CustomDelegate ();

            BlinkID.Instance ().LicenseKey = "MZEFTUGV-******";
            BlinkID.Instance ().Delegate = customDelegate;
            isFrontCamera = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But then, this part can't see how write it in F#:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (BlinkIDImplementation))]
```

I try:

```
[<assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (BlinkIDImplementation))>]
```

And I get:

> Error FS0841: This attribute is not valid for use on this language
>   element. Assembly attributes should be attached to a 'do ()'
>   declaration, if necessary within an F# module.

Answer (score 1):

Just write this fragment:

```
[<assembly: ...>]
do ()
```

Comment: I try: `[<assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency>]` and get error. Also: `do (typeof BlinkIDImplementation)` neither work.

Comment: Did you try this? 
    `[<assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency>]`
    `do ()`

Comment: Yes. It still not work. Get error FS0001 `[<assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency>] do (typeof BlinkIDImplementation)`

Comment: Why you did not try _exactly_ that code, that i wrote? Remove "typeof BlinkIDImplementation" from your last comment. Just "do()".